# Multi-Node Tree Picker xpath filter

Tags: xpath, umbraco

I have problem with writing xpath expression that allows me to select nodes from current category.
Briefly I have folder with products , this folder contains categories , categories contains products.
My intension is to select only products from the category of my current location of tree picker.
For example , I am in category called computers so I have to be able to select only products from this category.

Any Idea ?

Comment: What about providing a specific XML document?

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is using the $currentPage variable as the starting point for your XPath expression. Something like the following example which is off the top my head and untested but worth a try:

```
$currentPage//product
```

or

```
$currentPage/descendant-or-self::Product
```

If you post up your current XPath expression it may also help others to understand where you are at already and provide more specific help.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for reply, my current expression is that: ./Product 
I am able to add products to treepicker, but I have ability to add product from different categories.

Comment: Do you have the "From Current" option selected for the XPath type?